# Simple web-based calculator does not show result

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

So I'm studying how to deploy some web-based application on Tomcat and so far I already have a simple webapp running on the webserver (localhost:8080/Calculator-1.0-SNAPSHOT/).

However, I need help with the application itself. It doesn't display the result of the calculation. Other functions are working though, like not accepting decimal numbers. The code can be found here: https://github.com/kirillrublevsky/Calculator

I have the following code in my controller:

```
package com.kirillrublevsky.app.controller;

import com.kirillrublevsky.app.service.CalculatorService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class CalculatorController {

    @Autowired
    private CalculatorService calculatorService;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/calculate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public double calculate(@RequestParam(value = "first", required = true) double first,
                            @RequestParam(value = "operation", required = true) String operation,
                            @RequestParam(value = "second", required = true) double second) {

        return calculatorService.calculate(first, operation, second);
    }
}
```

This is the CalculatorService code:

```
package com.kirillrublevsky.app.service.impl;

import com.kirillrublevsky.app.service.CalculatorService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CalculatorServiceImpl implements CalculatorService {

    @Override
    public double calculate(double first, String operation, double second) {

        double result = 0.0;

        switch (operation) {
            case "+":
                result = first + second;
                break;
            case "-":
                result = first - second;
                break;
            case "*":
                result = first * second;
                break;
            case "/":
                result = first / second;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is the .js script:

```
/* jQuery and AJAX */

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#calculate").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var first = parseFloat($("#first").val());
        var second = parseFloat($("#second").val());
        var operation = $("#operation").find("option:selected").text();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/calculate",
            data: {"first": first, "operation": operation, "second": second},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").text(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Simple Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="first" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="operation">
                <option>+</option>
                <option>-</option>
                <option>*</option>
                <option>/</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="second" required>
        </div>
        <span id="output">&nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="result">0.0</span></span>
    </form>
    <button id="calculate" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Calculate</button>
</div>
<script src="/resources/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. It's an awesome resource to help you get unstuck. When posting a question, it is best to post relevant parts of your code that are not working along with any errors you receive to help the debug process. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me to this awesome community. Sorry I'm not getting any error messages. But the calculate button does not seem to output the result. It looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/Pf7rype.png)

Comment: Please post the **relevant** parts of the code **in the post itself** rather than posting a link to the entire project.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already added the relevant parts of the code. :)